# Windows: two threads handling messages?

Tags: c, winapi

I want to have two threads to handle windows messages. One for key/mouse input in the client area (this thread also takes care of game logic) and one for the rest because I am making a game and some messages cause DefWindowProc() to block (thus freezing the game).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `DefWindowProc` doesn't really "block"... it's pretty fast. Can you give an example message that causes blocking?

Comment: It would be better if you keep your existing design, but instead run the slow responses on background threads to avoid freezing the game.

Comment: if you are moving or resizing the window, DefWindowProc blocks until you release the mouse button

Comment: There is a trivial test you can perform to see if this is really true. Create a timer with SetTimer, then process the WM_TIMER messages. Try sizing the window and see if you stop receiving the messages. You should find you still get them.

Comment: @Jonathan: Good point, but freezing a game while the user moves or resizes the window is quite reasonable.  In fact, that's what I'd want it to do.

Comment: @MikeKwan you might still be recieving messages, but it doesn't change the fact that it blocks the rest of the thread: use put a printf inside your loop but outside the message handling(PeekMessage) and you will see that it will not print anything:

Comment: @CareyGregory but for a multiplayer game this behaviour is no good

Comment: @Jonathan, I'm not sure if you're asking the right question here - or at least the right question to get the best answers ;) . If the problem is that you want to avoid the game blocking under specific circumstances, perhaps that's the question to ask - the best solution might not involve two threads at all. Is the real qu "How do I stop my game blocking when the user resizes?" - or are there other cases also?

Comment: Having some experience working on a multiplayer game - what's the big deal if the game freezes while the user attempts to move/resize the window?  As long as the game clock keeps up with the actual time on the next rendered frame, you should be able to handle this.  Just treat it like a system "burp" (that will inevitably happen anyway). Users will figure out real quick not to mess with the window during intense gameplay.

Comment: I don't see any blocking while resizing or dragging windows - the other messages do get processed - stuff appears in memos, lists, edits etc..  To stop the messages, I would have to write explicit code to stop them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to what Cody wrote, you most definitely can process messages from multiple threads.  However, this is not a customizable free-for-all.  Rather, windows have thread affinity: each thread will receive the messages sent or posted to windows created by that thread.  There's no way to have any window's messages delivered to any other thread.

For your particular situation, why not create a worker thread with its own hidden window and message loop?  Any time the main window receives a message you don't want to process in the main thread, post it to the other window, it will be queued to and processed by the worker thread.

Comment: Ah, I didn't mean to imply anything different. Perhaps I overstated it a bit. I've seen way too many people here get themselves into deep trouble trying to do UI work on non-UI threads.

Answer (score 1):

You should only need a single thread handling the message queue, which is what Windows already supplies. If you are doing anything which is computationally heavy, you should dispatch it off to a separate thread by creating a new one with CreateThread. If you find you are constantly doing this, then have that thread permanently there but signal it to do work when you need to.

Answer (score 1):

No, all messages need to be processed on a single thread. This single thread is often called the UI thread because it is the one that controls the user interface. Trying to process UI messages on a non-UI thread will just get you into trouble.

However, a common problem is applications that perform long-running, computationally-intensive tasks in response to particular messages. This doesn't work out well because while the code is running inside of the message handler, the application is unable to process *other* messages (threads can only do one thing at a time), and your UI becomes unresponsive.

The solution is to spin off another thread (or two or however many you need) and delegate the long-running, computationally-intensive tasks off to that thread. You'll still handle the messages on the single UI thread, but inside of the message handlers is where you'll pass off the task to the helper threads. You'll frequently hear this referred to as the "worker thread" or "background thread" pattern.

You can create additional threads using the [`CreateThread` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx). You can find a sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516.aspx).

In this case, it sounds like the [`QueueUserWorkItem` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684957.aspx) might be a simpler option. Sample code:

```
DWORD CALLBACK ThreadProc(LPVOID p)
{
    HWND hWnd = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(p);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        // do whatever
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_KEYDOWN: // or whatever message you want to respond to
        {
            QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadProc, hWnd, WT_EXECUTELONGFUNCTION);
            return 0;
        }
        // process other messages...
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Required reading on Win32 thread pools is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686760.aspx).

Comment: You can have more than one UI thread, however each window is associated with only one thread, to which its messages will be delivered.